# What is the meaning of "Frozen" attribute?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

My model.xml file contain following code fragment. but I don't know why they are used.I used Spring and Hibernate technologies to build the project. hopes some expert explanation about this code fragment and the attributes?

```
<one-to-one fetch-type="lazy"  name="followUp" type="FollowUp" synthetic="true"
            nullable="true" access="frozen">
            <documentation>Synthetic property of the latest follow ups made for
                this Prescription.
            </documentation>
        </one-to-one>
```

Comment: do you have your own class called `frozen` anywhere in your code?  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html 
  (5.1.13) - "access" is "field", "property" or _the name of a custom class used to determine the strategy_.

Comment: @MrSpoon I checked my project but cannot find such class, any way. this is huge code base project and some time it may be contain in mevne repos , i will checked so far.(I haven't access permission some module)